# Very simple asymmetric RSA encryption in C#

Tags: c#, security, cryptography

Based on this: [asymmetric encryption in C#](http://www.csharpdeveloping.net/Snippet/how_to_encrypt_decrypt_using_asymmetric_algorithm_rsa)

I added some more functionality to make it even easier to use (I combined the `keySize` and the `keys` into one base64 string).

My requirements are:

- I want a public and private string key
- A simple method to call to encrypt or decrypt another string.

---

This works, and the following test case returns that all is good.

```
[TestMethod]
public void EncryptionRSATest()
{
    int keySize = 1024;   
    var keys = EncryptorRSA.GenerateKeys(keySize);

    string text = "text for encryption";

    string encrypted = EncryptorRSA.EncryptText(text, keys.PublicKey);
    string decrypted = EncryptorRSA.DecryptText(encrypted, keys.PrivateKey);

    Assert.IsTrue(text == decrypted);
}
```

So..

1. Can anyone help make it even better? Are there any major flaws in this that makes it really easy to decrypt?
2. Is it a horrible idea to add the `keySize` to the key?

This is the class:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

namespace JensB.Encryption
{
    [Serializable]
    public class EncryptorRSAKeys
    {
        public string PublicKey { get; set; }
        public string PrivateKey { get; set; }
    }

    public static class EncryptorRSA
    {
        private static bool _optimalAsymmetricEncryptionPadding = false;

        public static EncryptorRSAKeys GenerateKeys(int keySize)
        {
            if (keySize % 2 != 0 || keySize < 512)
                throw new Exception("Key should be multiple of two and greater than 512.");

            var response = new EncryptorRSAKeys();

            using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize))
            {
                var publicKey = provider.ToXmlString(false);
                var privateKey = provider.ToXmlString(true);

                var publicKeyWithSize= IncludeKeyInEncryptionString(publicKey, keySize);
                var privateKeyWithSize = IncludeKeyInEncryptionString(privateKey, keySize);

                response.PublicKey = publicKeyWithSize;
                response.PrivateKey = privateKeyWithSize;
            }

            return response;
        }

        public static string EncryptText(string text, string publicKey)
        {
            int keySize = 0;
            string publicKeyXml = "";

            GetKeyFromEncryptionString(publicKey, out keySize, out publicKeyXml);

            var encrypted = Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text), keySize, publicKeyXml);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
        }

        private static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, int keySize, string publicKeyXml)
        {
            if (data == null || data.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Data are empty", "data");
            int maxLength = GetMaxDataLength(keySize);
            if (data.Length > maxLength) throw new ArgumentException(String.Format("Maximum data length is {0}", maxLength), "data");
            if (!IsKeySizeValid(keySize)) throw new ArgumentException("Key size is not valid", "keySize");
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(publicKeyXml)) throw new ArgumentException("Key is null or empty", "publicKeyXml");

            using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize))
            {
                provider.FromXmlString(publicKeyXml);
                return provider.Encrypt(data, _optimalAsymmetricEncryptionPadding);
            }
        }

        public static string DecryptText(string text, string privateKey)
        {
            int keySize = 0;
            string publicAndPrivateKeyXml = "";

            GetKeyFromEncryptionString(privateKey, out keySize, out publicAndPrivateKeyXml);

            var decrypted = Decrypt(Convert.FromBase64String(text), keySize, publicAndPrivateKeyXml);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted);
        }

        private static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data, int keySize, string publicAndPrivateKeyXml)
        {
            if (data == null || data.Length == 0) throw new ArgumentException("Data are empty", "data");
            if (!IsKeySizeValid(keySize)) throw new ArgumentException("Key size is not valid", "keySize");
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(publicAndPrivateKeyXml)) throw new ArgumentException("Key is null or empty", "publicAndPrivateKeyXml");

            using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(keySize))
            {
                provider.FromXmlString(publicAndPrivateKeyXml);
                return provider.Decrypt(data, _optimalAsymmetricEncryptionPadding);
            }
        }

        public static int GetMaxDataLength(int keySize)
        {
            if (_optimalAsymmetricEncryptionPadding)
            {
                return ((keySize - 384) / 8) + 7;
            }
            return ((keySize - 384) / 8) + 37;
        }

        public static bool IsKeySizeValid(int keySize)
        {
            return keySize >= 384 &&
                    keySize <= 16384 &&
                    keySize % 8 == 0;
        }

        private static string IncludeKeyInEncryptionString(string publicKey, int keySize)
        {
            return Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( keySize.ToString() + "!" + publicKey));
        }

        private static void GetKeyFromEncryptionString(string rawkey, out int keySize, out string xmlKey)
        {
            keySize = 0;
            xmlKey = "";

            if (rawkey != null && rawkey.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] keyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(rawkey);
                var stringKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(keyBytes);

                if (stringKey.Contains("!"))
                {
                    var splittedValues = stringKey.Split(new char[] { '!' }, 2);

                    try
                    {
                        keySize = int.Parse(splittedValues[0]);
                        xmlKey = splittedValues[1];
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing this just for learning, right? It's almost impossible to write good crypto on your own. My first comment would be, a a data structure should hold one key. The benefit of asymmetric encryption is anyone can encrypt but only one with the private key can decrypt.

Comment: I am going to use this in a small application that transmits data in an enviroment where I cant use HTTPS. 

Good point with two separate key classes, one for public other for private.

Comment: Regarding the write my own crypto. I am using the RSACryptoServiceProvider which comes with C#, the only thing I am really doing myself is how I am packaging and storing the keys as to make it easier to work with.

Answer (score 4):

### Use proper Exception types

> ```
> throw new Exception("Key should be multiple of two and greater than 512.");
> ```

It's not recommended to throw objects of type `Exception`. That's the base type for many kinds of exceptions! If you catch it you'll end up catching a bunch of other stuff. It's preferable to create your own type that inherits from `Exception` or one of its child classes such as [`ArgumentOutOfRangeException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentoutofrangeexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also, use the most specific exception possible; for instance

> ```
> if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(publicKeyXml)) throw new ArgumentException("Key is null or empty", "publicKeyXml");
> ```

should use [`ArgumentNullException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). If you end up having a lot of exceptions that are more specific than something provided, create a child class.

### Magic constants make code hard to understand

> ```
> var publicKey = provider.ToXmlString(false);
> var privateKey = provider.ToXmlString(true);
> ```

The `false` and `true` look like magic here. It's not clear what their purpose is. Instead of just using the `bool` literal, use the name of the parameter:

```
var publicKey = provider.ToXmlString(includePrivateParameters: false);
var privateKey = provider.ToXmlString(includePrivateParameters: true);
```

### Pokemon exception handling

> ```
> try
> {
>    keySize = int.Parse(splittedValues[0]);
>    xmlKey = splittedValues[1];
> }
> catch (Exception e) { }
> ```

Why Pokemon? Because this code "gotta catch 'em all!". Seriously, this is a bad practice, it ends up catching exceptions you don't want to (for instance what if `splittedValues` ends up having only one element). Instead you should use `int.TryParse()`.